# How do I insert an improved dictionary into my collection in C# (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, windows-store-apps

Hi I have found out that using a dictionary directly into a Combo Box does not work well for Windows Store apps. This was my full code that produced the error.

My Model

```
 class QuestionModel
{
    public QuestionModel(int Key, string Question, Dictionary<string, string> Answers)
    {
    key = Key;
    question = Question;
        answers=Answers;
    }

    public int key { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> answers { get; set; }
}
```

Populating the collection code

```
    ObservableCollection<QuestionModel> questionCollection = new ObservableCollection<QuestionModel>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, string>> pair in CommonVariables.answersINR)
                    {

                        if (item.Key==pair.Key)
                        {
                         questionCollection.Add(new QuestionModel(item.Key, item.Value,pair.Value));

   }
   }
```

My Xaml combo box

```
 <ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="QuestioncomboBox" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=answers}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value">
                    </ComboBox>
```

So as you can see the pair. value loads data in the answer section of my collection. But I just found out today through research that Windows Store Apps Combo box does not work well with the dictionary. So someone in stack modified pair.value to this line of code.

```
pair.Value.Select(f => new { Key = f.Key, Value = f.Value }).ToList();
```

Which works perfectly for populating the Combo Box. The only thing is how do I insert it into the questioncollection instead of pair.value? Can someone please help by rewriting my code to fit the line of code above like this?

```
questionCollection.Add(new QuestionModel(item.Key, item.Value,pair.Value.Select(f => new { Key = f.Key, Value = f.Value }).ToList();));
```

At the moment that gives me an error I cannot solve?

Comment: Are you showing an ItemsControl with a List (IEnumerable, ObservableCollection...) of QuestionModel or just one?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change "public Dictionary<string, string> answers { get; set; }" into "public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> answers { get; set; }"